# For loop to connect to 3 machines and get the disk space and convert the values

Tags: windows, powershell, foreach, schedule

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01 {Get-PSDrive D} | Select-Object PSComputerName,Used,Free

Invoke-Command -ComputerName server02 {Get-PSDrive D} | Select-Object PSComputerName,Used,Freecode 


Invoke-Command -ComputerName server03 {Get-PSDrive D} | Select-Object PSComputerName,Used,Free
```

OUTPUT:

```
PSComputerName   Used                      Free
server01         2534760280064             256550076416
server02         2534760280061             20000000010
server03        2534760280061              2000000001011
```

DESIRED OUTPUT: That will send an email.

```
server01         2.53T                    238.9G
server02         2.53T                    18.62G
server03         2.53T                    1.86T
```

I think the 2nd column or USED SPACE will be divided by 1000000000 and the Free Space or 3rd Column will be divded by 1073741824.

Comment: Not an answer but as an aside, you could probably reduce this to a single command by doing `Invoke-Command -ComputerName server01,server02,server03 {Get-PSDrive D} | Select ..`

Comment: Thank you..I just make it one line/ Do you know how can i make this as a body. and will send via email?

Comment: Look up `Send-MailMessage` for how to send email with PowerShell.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to use here is a Calculated Property, which allows you to perform operations on values in the pipeline.

Here's the syntax, just add this to your `Select-Object` list of properties.

`@{ Name = '';  Expression = {}}`

So to use it in your example

```
Select-Object PSComputerName,@{ Name = 'Used (TB)';  Expression = {$_.Used/1tb}},Free
```

You can add additional logic within the Expression Script block to alternate between GB and TB, but this answer should get you heading in the right direction.

If you find that this carries too many digits, you can round up to the nearest tenth using the .net class `[math]` and its static method of `::Round()`.   Round takes two inputs (or overloads, as we call them in methods), like this.

```
[math]::Round(NumberToBeRounded, PositionsToRound)
[math]::Round(3.14159627, 3)
>3.141
```

So, to round your hard drive space figures:

```
"$([math]::Round(($_.Used/1gb),2)) GB"


PSComputerName Used 
-------------- ---------
localhost      1454.39 GB
```

Comment: Hi, Is there any way, we can reduce the decimals? i have like 8 decimals